# More Viewport windows = slower switching back from Full Screen?

Tags: 3d-view, performance, hardware

I finally upgraded from 3.6 to 4.0 and immediately noticed a huge impact to my workflow speed when **switching back-and-forth between a 4-pane viewport setup and Full Screen**.  I'm seeing about 3 seconds of delay when I'm in Full-Screen and hit CNTRL-SPACE to return back to the 4-panes.

I did a little experiment and can see **the delay increases with the number of Viewport panes**:

- Base Blender with 1 Viewport and 1 cube:  ~ 0.5 second delay going Full Screen and back
- Add 1 vertical split (2 viewports):  1.5 seconds delay returning from Full Screen
- Add 1 horizontal split (3 viewports):  2.5 seconds delay returning from Full Screen
- Add 1 horizontal split (4 viewports):  >3 seconds delay returning from Full Screen

It should be noted there's a slight increasing delay when entering Full Screen but I can tolerate it.  It's the 3 seconds every time I come back from Full Screen that's slowing me down.

I don't have a graphics card in my computer and would be willing to juice up my hardware but only if it helps this problem?  I'd appreciate any insight from the community before I get a new machine?

(BTW I've been using Blender for about 25 years back to the 1998 first public release.  It's remarkable to see how powerful it's become with the user community support over the years.  Let's keep it going and create amazing things together!)

Comment: If you think you've found a bug you should report it. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports